# How to use typescript relative/absotule paths

Tags: typescript, path, compilation, ts-node

Right now I need to write `import { MyFn } from '../lib/myUtils';` instead of `import { MyFn } from 'lib/myUtils';`.

My structure is:

```
tsconfig.json
src - 
    index.ts
    lib
       - myUtils
    ....
```

I dont want to use any external library like `module-alias`, I don't want to use `@` like in `@lib/myUtils`.

I just want to call `import { MyFn } from 'lib/myUtils';`.

How do I set up my compiler options?

Answer (score 0):

Use `"baseUrl": "./"` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

[Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl)